# Create a data frame from multiple data sets

Tags: apache-spark

I am practicing big data programming using apache spark with scala. I want to crate a data frame from multiple data sets located in a directory.  All data sets are in text/plain format with the same column names and data types. My question is how can i create a single data frame from these multiple data sets using scala?

Comment: its possible to pass multiple paths while reading the `DataFrame`. Read it as : `spark.read.format("csv").load("path1","path2",...)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `union` function. 
you can read data in 2 different df's and combine it together using the `union` function.

```
val df = firstDF.union(secondDF)
```